# A generic error occurred in GDI+ while encoding

Tags: c++-cli, system.drawing

I am working with an OCR project. I am trying to using an open source project source code. The project is written in C++. When I run the project it shows me an exception which is “A generic error occurred in GDI+”.I've tried all other stackoverflow solutions but nothing works. I find the exception where it happen but I am new with it. So, I don’t have idea about that exception. The exception is occurring here:

```
myEncoderParameters->Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
```

the whole function is

```
bool ImageProcessor::Save_UC_TIF_ImageFromSegmentedInformation(vector<vector<bool>> Img, int temporaryFileNumber){ 
    try{
        Bitmap^ nimg = gcnew Bitmap(wd, ht, PixelFormat::Format1bppIndexed);                 
        lineIndicator = 1;


        //lock the bits of the original bitmap
        BitmapData^ bmdo = nimg->LockBits(Rectangle(0, 0, wd, ht),                                ImageLockMode::ReadWrite, nimg->PixelFormat);

             lineIndicator = 2;

        for(int x=0; x<ht; x++){
            for(int y=0; y<wd; y++){
                if(Img[x][y]){
                    this->SetIndexedPixel(y, x, bmdo, 1);
                }else
                {
                    this->SetIndexedPixel(y, x, bmdo, 0);
                }
            }
        }

        //System::Drawing::Image::SetPropertyItem(
        nimg->UnlockBits(bmdo);
        lineIndicator = 3;

        // Now we need to set the compression information here
        ImageCodecInfo^ ico = GetEncoderInfo(ImageFormat::Tiff);
        lineIndicator = 4;
        // Create an Encoder object based on the GUID for the Compression parameter category.
        Encoder^ myEncoder = Encoder::Compression;
        //Encoder^ myEncoder = Encoder::Quality;

        lineIndicator = 5;
        // Create an EncoderParameters object. An EncoderParameters object has an array of EncoderParameter objects. 
        // In this case, there is only one EncoderParameter object in the array.
        EncoderParameters^ myEncoderParameters = gcnew EncoderParameters(1);
        lineIndicator = 6;
        EncoderParameter^ myEncoderParameter = gcnew EncoderParameter(myEncoder,   __int64(20));


        lineIndicator = 7;
        myEncoderParameters->Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        lineIndicator = 8;

        nimg->Save(System::Windows::Forms::Application::StartupPath + "\\Tesseract\\temp"+ temporaryFileNumber +".tif", ico, myEncoderParameters);
        lineIndicator = 9;
        return true;
    }
    catch(System::Exception^ ex)
    {
        System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show(ex->Message->ToString(), "Failed to Process the  Image  !!"+lineIndicator,System::Windows::Forms::MessageBoxButtons::OK,System::Windows::Forms::MessageBoxIcon::Error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please help for fixing this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't look like c#.  It looks like managed c++

Comment: Please don't add tags that do not directly relate to your question.

Comment: 20 is an unhappy number.  You'll have to choose 2, 3, 4 or 6 (lzw, ccitt3, ccitt4 or none).